# What is the fastest way to implement a class level property accessor in a singleton class?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I'd like to have a singleton class with some properties. Currently, I declare it like:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *myString;

+(MyClass *)sharedInstance;
+(NSString *)myString;
```

Is there a way to have a class-level accessor without writing a getter for each property?

Comment: Do you understand what a class-level method means? You access your string with `[MyClass sharedInstance].myString`. To access a property, you need to have an object of that class.

Comment: @LordZsolt Yeah, I understand. That's what I'm doing now. The question is whether it is possible to do so without having to write the getter.

Comment: @GoldenJoe You want to get a property without calling it's getter?

Comment: @Popeye No, I want to call a singleton's property without having to implement a class-level getter. Love your show by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I usually implement a singleton in this way:

*Singleton.h*

```
@interface Singleton : NSObject

+ (Singleton *)sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic) NSString *myProperty;

@end
```

*Singleton.m*

```
static Singleton *sharedInstance;

@implementation Singleton

+ (Singleton *)sharedInstance {
    if (!sharedInstance) {
        sharedInstance = [[Singleton alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.myProperty = @"Hello World";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Call:

```
NSLog(@"My Property: %@", [Singleton sharedInstance].myProperty);
```

But it sounds like you don't want to have to say `[Singleton sharedInstance]` every time.  Its a stretch, but you could try this:

*Singleton.h*

```
@interface Singleton : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *myProperty;

@end

static Singleton *singleton;

static inline Singleton *sharedInstance() {
    if (!singleton) {
        singleton = [[Singleton alloc] init];
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

*Singleton.m*

```
@implementation Singleton

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.myProperty = @"Hello World";
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Now you only have to call `sharedInstance().myProperty`